# converting XML gregorian calender to Date and string and vice versa

Tags: java

Many people might have tried to play with this....

I found a solution..thought it will be helpful to some one around.

```
XMLGregorianCalendar xmlGre=DatatypeFactory.newInstance().newXMLGregorianCalendar(new GregorianCalendar());

System.out.println(xmlGre.getXMLSchemaType());
Calendar cal=DatatypeConverter.parseDate(xmlGre.toXMLFormat());         
System.out.println(cal.getTime().toString());
```

Comment: 2002-12-16T16:20:10+04:00 is one type of date                                                      2013-12-03T16:41:52.399-05:00 is another type of date it can convert.The catch here is the time Zone. Simple date format can not convert the timezone if there is a colon inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2002-12-16T16:20:10+04:00 is one type of date

2013-12-03T16:41:52.399-05:00 is another type of date it can convert.

The catch here is the time Zone. Simple date format can not convert the timezone if there is a colon inside it.

{http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}dateTime is the xml element it is using.